# How to return value with apostrophe from excel UDF

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-addins

I have been trying to append ' before a value so that excel cells will recognize the cells as a text value.
Is there any way we can append ' with a value from UDF.

e.g If I call GetZero() it will return me '0.00 and excel will recognize it as 0.00 only(but as a text value).

Comment: Put double quotes "  around a number to get a string?

Comment: Usually you can just set the return type as string.  No need for the type specifier

Answer (score 0):

For your example

```
Public Function GetZero() As String
GetZero = "'" & format(0,"0.00")
End Function
```

Comment: I am trying this on C#. Once i set the value as: `GetZero = "'0.000" `                             it returns '0.000 which is the not the expected value. What i an trying to achieve is to get value as 0.000 so that i can apply +/-/* operations. Like $C$1 + 24.